# How does SuSE Linux's support for btrfs differ from Ubuntu and Fedora's?

Tags: btrfs

The [SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 2 release notes](http://www.novell.com/linux/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/11-SP2/#fate-306585) state that SuSE offers "commercial support" for btrfs, while Ubuntu and Fedora appear to be holding back until a working fsck utility is available. Does SuSE have some special tools/people to support btrfs that other distros don't?

(N.B. I'm aware that Oracle Linux also offers commercial support for btrfs, but they employ the main developer, so I can see how they have a special support capability).

Comment: Why would it differ? They both use the same kernel fs driver of brtfs

Comment: @warl0ck: I know it's the same software. I'm asking about support.

Comment: Interesting detail here is that Novell Suse does not support writing to ext4 filesystems. They are actively pushing btrfs.